# display category and sub category on home page menubar using jsp

Tags: java, servlets

I want to display categories and subcategory as menubar on my home page.  All categories should be there and subcategory are shown on mouse over on category menu.

I have tried servlet to fetch record and jsp to display it. My jsp code is as below

```
<ul>
    <% Iterator itr;%>
    <% List data=(List)request.getAttribute("data");
        for(itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
    %>
    <li><a href=""><%=itr.next()%></a></li>
    <%}%>
</ul>
```

With above method I can get category properly but the problem is that I want sub category which are store in anather table named as tbl_subcategory.  With above method I can get output as below:

> Home Aboutus  Sports Kitchen Baby-Toys

Now I want to display sub menus of each category on mouse over.

But it shows only category not subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's stored inside "data" but let's say it's loaded with Strings:

```
String data[] = new String[] { "Array 1", "Array 2", "Array 3" };
```

And the JSP-page would look something like this to print out all strings inside "data":

```
<ul>
  <% Iterator<String> iterator = request.getAttribute("data");
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  %>

  <li> <a href=""><%=iterator.next()%></a> </li>

  <%}%>
</ul>
```

And the generated HTML-page would look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Array 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Array 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Array 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Or you can use JSTL** to iterate through "data". Add this declaration in your HTML-Header:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And then iterate through "data":

```
<% String data[] = request.getAttribute("data"); %>

<ul>
<c:forEach var="d" items="${data}">
  <li><a href=""><c:out value="${d}" /></a></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

As for your dropdown menu take a look at [THIS TUTORIAL WITH A SIMPLE DROPDOWN MENU](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/#) which is for free. If you're looking for a more advanced dropdown menu look at [THIS TUTORIAL WITH A ADVANCED DROPDOWN MENU](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/multi_level_drop_down_menu/?st) but keep in mind though that this advanced dropdown menu costs money

I don't know where you're getting your submenuitems from but all I can say is that you should enter your submenu values inside the `<a>` tags to create submenuitems when you're using these tutorials. like this:

```
<li><a href="#" 
    onmouseover="mopen('m1')" 
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">Array 1</a>
    <div id="m1" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" 
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
    <a href="#">Array 1.1</a>
    <a href="#">Array 1.2</a>
    <a href="#">Array 1.3</a>
    </div>
</li>

<li><a href="#" 
    onmouseover="mopen('m2')" 
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">Array 2</a>
    <div id="m2" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" 
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
    <a href="#">Array 2.1</a>
    <a href="#">Array 2.2</a>
    <a href="#">Array 2.3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Just follow the steps in the tutorials and you'll be fine

Comment: Thank you I want your need to add sub menu on mouse over

Comment: Are you looking for a menu with dropdown-selection when you put your mouse over menuitems? like [this](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/)

Comment: yes, That's what I want.There are two tables I have first is category and anather is subcategory..Now I am able to display menu(i.e in category table) but want dropdown-selection on mouse over menu items...Thank you

Comment: I can not pay for that isn't there any free tool or can you suggest me code for it..Thank you

Comment: the first tutorial is free. it shows all javascript and how you managed to build your dropdown menu

Comment: These are manual items of sub menu when I am trying from database it doesn't show output....code is.. <div class="parentmenu">
  <ul>
    <% Iterator itr1;%>
      <% List data1=(List)request.getAttribute("data1");
        for(itr1=data1.iterator(); itr1.hasNext(); ){
       %><li><a href=""><%=itr1.next()%></a> 
        <% Iterator itr;%>
        <% List data=(List)request.getAttribute("subdata");
         for(itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
         %>
       <ul>
       <li><%=itr.next()%></li>
       </ul>
       <%}%>
       </li>
       <%}%>
    </ul>
  </div>

Comment: You are right. With above method I can get category properly but the problem is that I want sub category which is stored in another table. With above method I can get output as below: Home Aboutus now I want to display sub menus of each category on mouse over.